# Inherit from Dict with Private Values on Object

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, inheritance

**EDIT - I Figured it out**

So I have the class as defined below:

```
class BaseLocation(dict):
    _ao = None
    _op = None

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        if iterable is None:
            iterable = {}
        self.update(iterable)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        """sets the attribute"""
        if key.startswith("_"):
            setattr(self, key, value)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    def __setattribute__ (self, key, value):
        super(BaseGeometry, self).__setattribute__(key, value)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __getattribute__ (self, name):
        return super(BaseGeometry, self).__getattribute__(name)

    def __getattr__(self, name): # support item attributes
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, name)
        except:
            raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (type(self).__name__, name))

    def __getitem__(self, k): 
        return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
```

The dictionary returned does not show the "_" values, which is fine.  I want these attributes to be private and not seen by the user.  My question is this, is how do I set these values?  If I do BaseLocation._ao = (1,0) and I print the BaseLocation object, I see `_ao` in the dictionary, which I never want to see.  So what do I need to do to hide this variable?

```
bl = BaseLocation({'x':1,'y':10})
bl._ao = 1
print(bl)
```

You will see `_ao` appears in the dict of the object.

Comment: Right now, your `_ao` and `_op` are *class* attributes. When you do `b1._ao = 1`, you're creating an *instance* attribute. So it's unclear to me what your desired result here is. Are they supposed to be class or instance attributes?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: **

```
class BaseGeometry(dict):
    _ao = None
    _op = None

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        if iterable is None:
            iterable = {}
        self.update(iterable)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        """sets the attribute"""
        if key in {'_ao','_op', '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            super(BaseGeometry, self).__setattr__(key,value)
        else:
            self[key] = value
    def __setattribute__ (self, key, value):
        if key in {'_ao','_op', '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            super(BaseGeometry, self).__setattr__(key,value)
        else:
            self[key] = value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    def __getattribute__ (self, name):
        return super(BaseGeometry, self).__getattribute__(name)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            if name in {'_ao','_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
                return super(BaseGeometry, self).__getattr__(k)
            return dict.__getitem__(self, name)
        except:
            raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (type(self).__name__, name))
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
```